# Using CharIndex, Len and Substring to locate certain information from a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, string-length

Here's what I am trying to do, but failing miserably:

I am trying to retrieve address from a column that is 12000+ characters long.  Lucky for me, I can locate the address line1 through  XML tag:

```
<PermanentAddress> <AddressLine><![CDATA[1234 1st street]]></AddressLine> <City>
```

Here's what I have done so far:

```
select 
substring(PC.css_record, CHARINDEX('<AddressLine>', PC.css_record)+ 21, CHARINDEX('</AddressLine>', PC.css_record))
from 
table1
```

I tried squeezing length function in there too to calculate the length end of my substring function, but that just gave me an error (may be because I am new to SQL and still learning and used it wrong).

Also, there are multiple  tags, but I am only concerned with the first one.

It would be very awesome if someone could help me out!

Thanks!

Comment: are u storing the XML data as `varchar` instead of `XML` type ?

Comment: Yes. I didnt see the point in using it was xml type since i wanted just a small part of the information for my report.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
declare @xml xml = 
'<PermanentAddress> 
<AddressLine><![CDATA[1234 1st street]]>
</AddressLine> 
<City>test</City>
</PermanentAddress>'  

select @xml.value('(/PermanentAddress/AddressLine)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
```

Answer (score 3):

You found the beginning: `CHARINDEX('<AddressLine>', PC.css_record) + 21`
and the end: `CHARINDEX('</AddressLine>', PC.css_record) - 3`,
now you just need to compute the length by subtracting the beginning from the end:
`CHARINDEX('</AddressLine>', PC.css_record) - CHARINDEX('<AddressLine>', PC.css_record) - 24`

```
select 
    substring(PC.css_record,
              CHARINDEX('<AddressLine>', PC.css_record) + 21,
              CHARINDEX('</AddressLine>', PC.css_record)
                  - CHARINDEX('<AddressLine>', PC.css_record) - 24)
from 
PC
```

Comment: Thank you! You have helped me a big time!