# How to change a value between two characters SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

This question is divided into two parts. I will start with the first and obvious to the title:

On the frontend I save this value:

Hello you are: HERE The page you can visite is www.test.se

In the db i am trying to write a script that will change the value between ":" and "The"

Although the value that is stored is a bit diffirent in the db...there it looks like this:

```
"Hello you are: <br/> <br/> <br/> HERE <br/><br/><br/><br/>The page 
you can visite is" www.test.se
```

I want to change "HERE" to "XXXX"

My attempt so far:
I found these two soloutions that are simillar to my question

[Soloution One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388432/how-to-extract-strings-between-two-special-characters-in-tsql)

[Soloution Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16784117/using-charindex-len-and-substring-to-locate-certain-information-from-a-column)

Sadly i could not get this to work...I attempted this:

```
select SUBSTRING(
        body, 
        CHARINDEX(':', body) +1 , 
        CHARINDEX('The',body)) 
         from @temp
```

I read up on substring and i am aware of that the last paramater is how long from the start position it should go but i want it to stopp at "The" and dont really know how to.

Second part of this question:

I only want to change the value of "HERE" how can i do that and avoid deleting the br taggs?

EDIT:

The value that i am trying to change is not always the same so a simple update statment will not work, thats why i need to find the value that i want to change

Comment: are ther always three br tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT REPLACE(body, SUBSTRING(body, CHARINDEX(':', body) + 1, CHARINDEX('The page you can visite is', body) - (CHARINDEX(':', body) + 1)) ,' <br/> <br/> <br/> XXXX <br/><br/><br/><br/> ') 
FROM @temp
```

Note that I used complete fragment "The page you can visit is" with the CHARINDEX to reduce the possibility of that same subs-string being present in the "HERE" section.

Answer (score 0):

If your question can be answered using a regular expression replacing, which I think it can, use https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg it will provide you with functions such as `PREG_REPLACE` to replace content matching a regular expression with other data